# Making HTTP request with Django and deserializing output

Tags: django, http, request

So I'm almost totally new to web development as a whole, but have been thrown into a side project using Django to pull and parse data from a web service, and am struggling to understand exactly how things work, even while looking through the Django documentation.

In Django, I have everything set up and working at a basic level (using templates, a page is displayed saying "Hello World").

Now in order to pull the data from the webservice, I need to make a request to a URL of the following format:

```
http://wbsapi.withings.net/[service_name]?action=[action_name]&[parameters]
```

In the provided PHP example, they do this using cURL, and then json_decode.

What would I do to get similar functionality out of Django? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You would use `urllib2` and `json` standard modules (or, alternatively, the excellent library [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and `json`):

```
import urllib2
import json

url = 'http://wbsapi.withings.net/[service_name]?action=[action_name]&[parameters]'
serialized_data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

data = json.loads(serialized_data)
```

If you want it on a page, you want it in a [view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/views/), which you will need to [associate with an url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/urls/).

Your `urls.py` will contain something like

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^get_data/$', 'myapp.views.get_data'),
)
```

And your `myapp/views.py` will contain something like

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import urllib2
import json

def get_data(request):
    url = 'http://wbsapi.withings.net/[service_name]?action=[action_name]&[parameters]'
    serialized_data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

    data = json.loads(serialized_data)

    html = "<html><body><pre>Data: %s.</pre></body></html>" % json.dumps(data, indent=2)

    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Of course, I don't know how you wanted your data to be displayed, so I just serialized it again :)

Comment: Where would I put this within the app? Would it have its own python file? Would it go in views.py? Sorry I have so many questions! Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: For now, very basic. I want to be able to send the request, get the json data, deserialize it, and display it on a page.

Comment: Thanks very much Pavel! The overall structure of the app is starting to make a lot more sense now. The only error I'm running into right now is the page says:

`Using the URLconf defined in withings.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^get_data/$

The current URL, , didn't match any of these.`

How can I fix this?

Comment: You're trying to request an url you didn't define. The only url available is "/get_data/". Did you forget any of the slashes?

Comment: I ended up figuring it out. Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: @Pavel Anossov is urllib2.urlopen going to block all website till roundtrip of request finishes?

Comment: @PavelAnossov Thanks a lot sir :)

Answer (score 0):

While it would be possible to implement this sort of functionality in Django, there's a bunch of intermediary steps involved.  First, you should just think about how you're going to use Python to query the webservice.  For this, I would highly recommend [the Requests module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), which is great for this.