# How to programmatically call a Django Rest Framework view within another view?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following generic class based views built with Django Rest framework (DRF)

```
class ExampleDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Example.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExampleSerializer
    renderer_classes = (JSONRenderer, TemplateHTMLRenderer)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        response = self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if request.accepted_renderer.format == 'html':
            form = ExampleForm(data=response.data)
            return Response({'data': response.data, 'form': form}, template_name='example.html')

        return response
```

This view allow me to obtain both JSON data or HTML form from the same endpoint by specifying the format=json or html.

**I would like to programmatically call that view** to obtain the rendered HTML form from within another view in order to include this form in another page that will include more stuff.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
html_from_view = ExampleDetail.as_view({'get': 'list'})(request).content
```

OR

```
html_from_view = ExampleDetail.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'})(request, pk=my_id).render().content
```

Comment: what is the request ? , and if I'm in one ipython shell

Comment: @Sérgio Read the question. The `request` is the same that was passed to the original view function / get method. If you are in a ipython shell, you have to use another approach. For example, you can emulate a http request using the django test client. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#overview-and-a-quick-example

Comment: The above works now, 5 years later, except use `request._request` instead of `request`.

Comment: This solution works for the ViewSet but not APIView. The solution provided by JD Solanki below works for APIView.

Comment: But how do you create the HttpRequest object programmatically with a body when the body is read-only? An HttpRequest object is required. And for POST requests with a body there appears to be no way whatsoever to create the body programmatically.

Comment: It looks like in order to change the body you need custom middleware: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740310/how-to-update-django-httprequest-body-in-middleware but then the code in this answer doesn't trigger middleware when it is called. So how on earth do you programatically do this?

Answer (score 41):

I found the solution for this in the documentation... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins/

Hint is from their example here:

```
class AuthorDetail(View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = AuthorDisplay.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = AuthorInterest.as_view()
        return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Does not work. I get ```The `request` argument must be an instance of `django.http.HttpRequest`, not `rest_framework.request.Request`.```

Comment: It's certainly possible both projects have diverged in how they treat things ... I haven't played with this in awhile.

Comment: Looks like someone (Greg Brown) proposed an edit that those calls should be `return view(request._request, *args, **kwargs)` -- maybe that is the "newer" way to do it, @waqasgard...worth trying I think. Leaving the answer as-is, since it matches the linked documentation and was valid for older versions of Django.

Comment: Here's the link to the 4.0 documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/mixins/#avoid-anything-more-complex
It has the same example.

Answer (score 21):

As of Django 2.2 and DRF 3.9.2 I am able to get response using below code.

```py
response = UserItemsApiView.as_view()(request=request._request).data
```

Above example solves below issues:

- The `request` argument must be an instance of `django.http.HttpRequest`, not `rest_framework.request.Request`
- Instead of `content`, using `data` attribute gave me result from that view.

Comment: I get "b'{"detail":"CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."}'" when trying this, any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of some of the answers was confusing to me, even though that's how the django docs explain it:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view

So here's an answer that's a little more understandable for my small brain:

```
class MyTemplateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'my_template.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        view = MyApiView.as_view()
        response = view(request=self.request)
        data = response.data
        context["somedata"] = data
        return context
```

Answer (score -10):

If I'm understanding correctly, you need to get the result from view B, while inside view A.

Using the **requests**/**urllib2** and **json** libraries should solve your problem (as specified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14143433/making-http-request-with-django-and-deserializing-output)).

To get the URL, you can use a combination of *request.get_absolute_uri()* and/or *request.get_host()* and *django.core.urlresolvers.reverse*.