# Django rest framework call a viewset programatically passing authentication headers from another view

Tags: django, authentication, view, django-rest-framework

I am trying to call an api made with Django Rest Framework `drf`. My case is that I want to call the api from another view get the response and display the data in a template. I have referred to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790981/how-to-programatically-call-a-django-rest-framework-view-within-another-view), but could not make a successful call since my viewset requires authentication. Viewset works perfect if called using urls, the default way. Viewset is as below

```
class ViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows Objects to be viewed or edited.
    """
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Myclass.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MyclassSerializer
    ....
    ....
    return response(json)
```

On calling this api from another view the response that I get is a `401 page` from drf api.

```
 ipdb>view = Myview.as_view({'get':'list'}
 ipdb>obj=view(request, *args, **kwargs)
 ipdb> obj.data
 {u'detail': u'Authentication credentials were not provided.'}
 ipdb>obj.has_header('Authentication')
 False
```

I tried passing Authentication headers also, but I dont know whether its the right way.

```
  view = MyViewSet.as_view({'get':'list'},{'token':'token'})
```

This returned an error argument token is not accepted. And I tried

```
view = MyViewSet.as_view({'get':'list'},Authentication={'token':'token'})
```

But this Also returned me errors. How is it possible to call an api viewset from another view by passing auth params?

TIA

Comment: Why do you want to call whole view? Can't it be done by re-using `MyClassSerializer` and maybe some other parts from that view in your second view?

Comment: Its like  I am using api and I don't want to rewrite the view in django ORM. I want to fetch data as json using drf api and return template  using django views

Comment: You can use serializer here to deal with it - if there is noting in view that is doing something more around your data, it won't be hard.

Comment: It would be very helpful if  you exemplify a bit more.

Comment: I believe if you pass the incoming request directly to your other view, the authentication should work. Here is the example on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26790981/399435