# Django rest Framework sending json to api endpoint within another class-based view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to post to an endpoint from within a CBV and retrieve the response (in order to access the id of the created resource). I've had a look at [How to programmatically call a Django Rest Framework view within another view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790981/how-to-programmatically-call-a-django-rest-framework-view-within-another-view) but cannot find how to send field values through with the request object. request.data is immutable, and passing kwargs through doesn't seem to be doing anything:

```
from app.views import OtherViewSet

class NewViews(APIView):
   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       # kwargs value here is {'field1':1, 'field2':2...}
       view_func = OtherViewSet({'post':'create'})
       response = view_func(self.request, *args, **kwargs).data
```

Although the kwargs contains the field values (set through several url named groups), the response always looks like:

```
{'field1': ['This field is required'], 'field2':['This field is required...
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks all :)

Edit:
Once I've got the ID of the created resource, I want to retrieve the resource as rendered by a particular (custom) format (I don't want to return the response object above).

Comment: Why not use a specific serializer, that may reuse the serializer from `OtherViewSet` ???

Comment: @GabrielMuj can you give an example here? I'm not sure how this would look - I need to access the data after making a request to the OtherViewSet's create endpoint within this view.

Comment: Can you provide the serializer from `OtherViewSet` and what data you need in `NewView`?

Comment: I could do, but it doesn't seem particularly DRY. I also want to return the result in a particular format so need to render the response via one of our custom renderers.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe you can reuse the serializer from `Otherviewset` by subclass it.

Answer (score 0):

**views.py**

```
from app.views import OtherViewSet

class NewViews(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        view = OtherViewSet.as_view({'post':'create'})
        response = view(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return response
```

Comment: I get: django.http.request.RawPostDataException: You cannot access body after reading from request's data stream. However, I need to access the data from the response, not return it.