# Perform post request using Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, post, django-rest-framework

I've got a Django rest framework APIView:

```
class MyAPIView(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        field = request.POST.get("field")
        print(field)
        return Response({"field": field}, status=200)
```

I want to call it from separate process using Django API. I do it like this:

```
from django.http import HttpRequest, QueryDict

request = HttpRequest()
request.method = "POST"
request.POST = QueryDict(mutable=True)
request.POST["field"] = "5"
response = MyAPIView.as_view()(request=request)
```

But when `field` is being printed in MyAPIView it's always `None`.
How to call post method using Django?

Answer (score 2):

1. If you need to call on view from another view - check this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790981/how-to-programmatically-call-a-django-rest-framework-view-within-another-view)
2. If you need to send request to the view

`pip install requests` or `poetry add requests`

```
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
import requests as client

DOMAIN = "http://127.0.0.1:8080"

# your endpoint name (path name in urls.py)
# you can get name using django extenstions command `show_urls` if you dont know the path name
endpoint = reverse("my-api-view")

client.post(f"{DOMAIN}{endpoint}", data={"field": "5"})
```

[django extensions](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

[command show_urls](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_extensions.html?highlight=show_urls#command-extensions)

usage: `python manage.py show_urls`

3. If you need exactly run the code of some view, why you cannot move this code to some function/static-method and call it in view and in other part of code?

Comment: In case of 3 some usefull information such as user, permissions, ect is missing. I know there's a way to make requests using requests package, but I'm interested in making it using Django or Django rest framework.

Comment: u dont need to send request to view from the same django project. only in api tests.

Comment: in tests you need to use APIClient and reverse to send request and test you apiview